# Stored procedure call error in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a stored procedure in my SQL Server that starts with these lines code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_Notify]
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@UserName nvarchar(50),
@lastDate datetime
AS
BEGIN

-- my code...
```

I try to call the stored procedure using this code:

```
DECLARE @data datetime
DECLARE @Username nvarchar(50)
SET @Username = CAST('myUserName' AS nvarchar(50))
SET @data = GetDate()
SP_Notify @Username , @data
```

but this causes this error:

> *Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
>
>   Syntax error near 'SP_Notify'.*

Comment: You should **NOT** use the `sp_` prefix for your own stored procedure - this prefix is reserved by Microsoft and could cause trouble in the future

Comment: Here's a MSDN link confirming Marc's point: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd172115%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: And something a little more thorough: http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `exec SP_Notify @Username,@data`

Answer (score 5):

You need to add [`EXEC`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258848%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) before the stored procedure call:

```
DECLARE @data datetime
DECLARE @Username nvarchar(50)
SET @Username = CAST('myUserName' AS nvarchar(50))
SET @data = GetDate()
EXEC SP_Notify @Username , @data
```

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
DECLARE @data datetime
DECLARE @Username nvarchar(50)
SET @Username = CAST('myUserName' AS nvarchar(50))
SET @data = GetDate()

EXEC SP_Notify @Username = @Username, @lastDate = @data
```

I've added `EXEC`, and specified the parameter values rather than relying on ordinal position to pass them in (this can come back to bite you otherwise, perhaps if you modify the SP in future, re-ordering and/or adding parameters).

Comment: the last parameter should be `@lastDate = @data`.